# Cluster of two instances of WSO2 api manager token verification failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm facing this error:

```
ERROR - JWTValidator Invalid JWT token. XXXXX":"RS256"}
```

I'm using wso2 api manager cluster of two all in one nodes. After generating token and after some calls the client receive.

[image]

So the client is forced to generate new jwt token before making another request.

I've checked if there's a significant time difference between the systems in the cluster but two servers have same clock.

Note that I stopped one of the servers then generated the token on the only asset then I stopped the server which was used to generate the token then I started the other and tested a request with the token obtained with the other server and its working. only the token seems to be revoked or expired before time.

Comment: Do you have the same Certificates(Keystores) on both servers?

Comment: Yes the certificate is the same. And one jwt token work with all two nodes

Comment: And note that when i'm using Insomnia Or Postman or swagger in devPortal this error never occur I think it's because of the cookies that the error does not occur

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finaly i've solved the problem by using scope in your token request, something like this:

`curl -k -X POST https://myapi-manager-domain.com/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=device_<unique value>" -H "Authorization: Basic Base64(<consumer-key>:<consumer-secret>)"`

You can found more details there : https://medium.com/@vinula9/scope-allowlisting-whitelisting-in-wso2-api-manager-for-generating-access-tokens-per-device-or-9d16746c048b